# The C compiler identification is unknown when compile C++ in Mac Mojave

Tags: c++

I am compiling a simple c++ file in Mac OS Majave:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake .
```

current folder contains a file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

And the error output is:

```
dolphins-MacBook-Air:untitled dolphin$ /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /Users/dolphin/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

The cc environment variable is:

```
dolphins-MacBook-Air:untitled dolphin$ env |grep gcc
CC=/Users/dolphin/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
```

Where is going wrong?

Comment: Well. Does the path actually exist? It’s a bit odd that your Xcode would be on the desktop to start with; — a symlink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the path for CXX also. Like below:

```
export CC=/path/to/gcc
export CXX=/path/to/g++
# Then cmake will find the compilers
```

Under linux, my compilers are stored here:

```
/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/g++
```

You can use `which gcc` and `which g++` to find the paths of the compilers, provided they can be found in your path.